# Parallax Mapping holes in texture

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, texture-coordinates

Hello i made a simple parallax set up that works but for some reason there is this problem.

As you can see the more steep the angle of view the more texture turns black and I don't know what's the reason for this

[image]

[image]

My shader set up
[image]

[image]

blend file here

Comment: Hello, could you please pack your image and share your file?

Comment: "Regular" Parallax mapping does not handle steep angles pretty well. You can look at Parallax Occlusion instead, as it's designed to tackle that issue.

Comment: @Venay do you know how to do it in blender ?

Comment: I've only worked with regular Parallax mapping before, but I'll try to figure out how to do it in Blender later after work. As far as I can recall, it involves implementing Parallax mapping with different samples and somehow interpolating between them.